# A polynomial from character theory

Tags: number-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group, and define $a(n)=\#\{g\in G\mid o(g)=n\}$.

In problem 5.18 of Isaacs' *Character Theory of Finite Groups*, the following polynomial is defined:

$$F_G(X)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_ma(m)X^{|G|/m}$$

**Theorem:** $F_G(k)$ is an integer for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Setting $G$ to be the cyclic group with $n$ elements, **define:**

$$g_n(X)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n}\varphi(d)X^{n/d}$$

**Questions:**

1. Does $g_n$ have some other significance, in some other context? Perhaps in number theory?
2. Is there a more direct way to show that $g_n(k)$ is an integer for every integer $k$?

In the special case that $n=p$ for some prime $p$,

$$g_p(X)=\frac{1}{p}(X^p+(p-1)X)$$.

It follows easily from Fermat's Little Theorem that $g_p(k)$ is an integer for integer values of $k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It plays a role in combinatorics. $g_n(k)$ counts the number of necklaces with $n$ beads chosen from $k$ colors (up to rotationary symmetry). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)
2. Follows from 1. :-)

Comment: Thank you! The necklace interpretation mirrors the character-theoretic interpretation perfectly, if one thinks of a particular $k$-coloring of an $n$-necklace as a function from $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to the set of $k$ colours.